Why is the syntax for LESS Accessors like this?
I am hoping to get clarification on why Less "accessors" work in the way demonstrated in a particular example.
What follows is taken from the tutorial "Less - Namespaces and Accessors" by TutorialsPoint.
style.less
.class1 {
   .class2 {
      .val(@param) {
         font-size: @param;
         color:green;
      }
   }
}

.myclass {
   .class1 > .class2 > .val(20px);
}

Compiled result ↓
style.css
.myclass {
   font-size: 20px;
   color: green;
}

Aside from this example demonstrating a more verbose way of accomplishing something simple (making it perhaps not such an ideal example), its syntax is also confusing to me.
What I find confusing is that the value of 20px is assigned at .val(20px); and then called(?) in lines before that at .val(@param) {...
I was instead expecting a syntax more like @param: 20px; for assignment, as is demonstrated in a prior lesson "Less - Functions". This lesson about functions made sense to me.
The "Namespaces and Accessors" lesson doesn't actually explain why the 20px value is assigned in the place where it is, or why the variable @param appears twice above. (I am referring to it being both here: .val(@param) and here: font-size: @param;) I guess the font-size property is inheriting from the .val class, but none of this is really explained in the lesson.
Can somebody please explain the flow of this logic and the reasoning behind it?
Thanks.
